# CRIR & jQuery - hooking up a method to fire after CRIR loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSP that uses jQuery and [CRIR](http://www.chriserwin.com/scripts/crir/) to display a form with radio buttons. I'm using CRIR to style the radio buttons to give them a custom look.

CRIR appears to [set itself up](http://www.chriserwin.com/scripts/crir/crir/crir.js) on load with something like this:

```
crir.addEvent(window, 'load', crir.init, false);
```

I want to perform some initialization on page load *but after* `crir.init` (because `crir.init` sets all the radio buttons up). When I use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    updateUIOnLoad();
});
```

it appears to get called *before* `crir.init`.

I'm not familiar with Javascript events, so I was wondering if there was a way to set things up so that a function would execute on document load but after `crir.init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, so far as I can tell, is that crir is setting itself up on the window's 'load' event, whereas your jQuery's responding on the document 'ready' event (which, as you've seen, precedes the window's 'load' event).

You could change the jQuery to:

```
$(window).load(
  function(){
    updateUIOnLoad();
  });
```

So long as this follows the call to crir in the mark-up, it should work (and does, on localhost, but sadly I couldn't make a JS Fiddle demo work properly).

Also you can test for crir as part of a function call:

```
$(window).load(
  function(){
    if (crir) {
      updateUIOnLoad();
    }
  });
```

There's a demo of this, sort of, [working on my site at: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/soCrir.html](http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/soCrir.html).